# DC.JS get last month value as filter

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter, stock

I've got a question concerning measures that can't be aggregated over time, for example stock value. In the example below, I've created a time line for my total stock value, which works well. Additionally I would like to see the most current stock level per company. This should be last month of my time selection. I can't get this to work as the stock value is being summed over the entire period, where I would like to see the stock value of the last period (month).

Whenever I change my selection in the chartMonth, the stock value in the chartCompany should adjust accordingly. I think I need to explicitly define a filter on my dimCompany or grpCompant, but I really don't have a clue how to proceed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = [{date:"201501",company:"A",stock:1200}
        ,   {date:"201502",company:"A",stock:1400}
        ,   {date:"201503",company:"A",stock:1300}
        ,   {date:"201504",company:"A",stock:1100}
        ,   {date:"201501",company:"B",stock:1000}
        ,   {date:"201502",company:"B",stock:1100}
        ,   {date:"201503",company:"B",stock:900}
        ,   {date:"201504",company:"B",stock:1200}];


    var dateFormat = d3.time.format('%Y%m');
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.dd = dateFormat.parse(d.date);
        d.year = d3.time.year(d.dd);
        d.month = d3.time.month(d.dd);
    });


    var     ndx = crossfilter(data)
        ,   dimMonth = ndx.dimension(function(d){return d.month})
        ,   dimCompany = ndx.dimension(function(d){return d.company;});

    var     grpMonth = dimMonth.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.stock;})
        ,   grpCompany = dimCompany.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.stock;});


var chartCompany = dc.barChart('#chartCompany');
var chartMonth = dc.lineChart('#chartMonth');

    chartCompany
        .width(400)
        .height(400)
        .margins({top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50})
        .dimension(dimCompany)
        .group(grpCompany)
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .elasticY(true);

    chartMonth
        .width(400)
        .height(400)
        .margins({top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50})
        .dimension(dimMonth)
        .group(grpMonth)
        .x(d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(2015, 5, 10, 6), new Date(2015, 5, 10, 18)]))
        .xUnits(d3.time.months)
        .elasticX(true);

    dc.renderAll();
    </script>
```

Comment: Crossfilter is not well-adapted to this sort of problem, but it is possible to do this with custom reducers. In your stock group you'll need to track all the values you see and then set the value of the group to be the last one. Removal will involve removing the record from your list of tracked values and updating the value of the group if necessary. If you put together a working example (jsFiddle), I can probably get it working for you. Otherwise there are custom reducer examples at https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ you can work from.

Comment: Thanks, I'll work on it and I'll post an example as soon as I've got someting ...